# Firestore chat app structure - Unread / read message schema

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an app with a social element in that users can have 1 to 1 conversations. At the moment a user can request a conversation with another user and upon acceptance, a cloud function is triggered which then assigns that conversation to both users. This works really well up to now and I have users being able to send each other messages instantly

My problem lies in that I want users to be notified of messages that haven't been read. I know that I could implement notifications via FCM but I also want the user to be able to see that a conversation has unread messages in their conversation list

Is this possible with firebase?

Edit: I should rephrase, I know this is possible. I just can't think of any structure that would be efficient. I could pass a messageRead Boolean property on each message, however I would need to update this property everytime a message is read by updating the field immediately after getting the documents.

Comment: i think you should save the timestamp of last time user read messages, and then you can compare the latest message time and latest read time and tell the user there are soke unread messages. So, instead of using a per message boolean, you ll use per room timestamp per user. To make it more efficient, you can save the timestamp periodically or with a better algorithm instead of each msg read.

Comment: @AlexMamo checked your videos. no information about unread/read messages. can u please update ur tutorial with this feature. Thank you.